# Access to hyperlink in a pdf(iPhone)?

Tags: iphone

I am working on a small app, which can open a pdf. My question is, if it is possible to access a hyperlink from a pdf? Because when am trying to click on hyperlink nothing is happening and it's not redirecting me to the link. I tried searching a lot but didn't got any luck on this. Am expecting a quick response as my work is getting delayed because of this issue. If it's possible then what would be the approach? Right now am using UIWebView to open the pdf. Any sample app or code will be of great help.

Thanks for your time .

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to use a third party library (or perhaps parse the PDF yourself), find the links, get their rects and catch user taps and compare that to the list of link/hyperlinks/gotos for that particular page.

Unfortunatelly - nothing in the SDK that can help. You can search for a opensource pdf library, like muPDF for instance.

There is a reason why not many applications have that functionality :D

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Even am thinking this is the only possible way. Wondering how come apple is not paying attention to this issue.